# Subquery in php function

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I have two tables in my database(phpmyadmin). I want to get the user1 in table1 and compare it with user2 in table2 using a function in php. It is not the primary key that i need to compare. How can i possibly do that?
Can i do something like this?

```
    public function userreservationdata($table,$table2)
    {
        $q = "SELECT user FROM $table WHERE user =(SELECT sname FROM $table2 WHERE sname=:sname) ";
        $stmt = $this->con->query($q);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
```

this code is suppose to output the result.(from a different file)

```
$reservations = $code->userreservationdata("user_list","reserve_list");
```

Thank YOu.

Comment: why not use an INNER JOIN ?

Comment: One more thing when you write sub queries like that normally you dont use "=" in the where clause of the main query, it has to be "IN" instead, coz sub query can return more than one row. (In your case there is a big chance of that happening coz sname is not unique )

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
 SELECT user FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.user=t2.user
```

Comment: it wont fetch  Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object

Comment: you have to replace table1 and table2 with what you want to use and make sure both tables have a colum named user or changed that to

Comment: yeah they will be changed here $reservations = $code->userreservationdata("user_list","reserve_list");

Comment: echo your query before it executes and see if its a valid SQL query or not